# Display Out of Stock status on products in WooCommerce archives except for specific metadata

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product

I'm using the following to display stock status on WooCommerce archives pages:

```
<?php
//add action give it the name of our function to run
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wcs_stock_text_shop_page', 25 );
//create our function
function wcs_stock_text_shop_page() {
    //returns an array with 2 items availability and class for CSS
    global $product;
    $availability = $product->get_availability();
    //check if availability in the array = string 'Out of Stock'
    //if so display on page.//if you want to display the 'in stock' messages as well just leave out this, == 'Out of stock'
    if ( $availability['availability'] == 'Out of stock') {
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_html', '<p class="stock ' . esc_attr( $availability['class'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $availability['availability'] ) . '</p>', $availability['availability'] );
    }
 
}
```

Does anyone know how I could edit the above code to exclude products with the meta `_ywpo_preorder`, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can check about that metadata in the postmeta table with the product id and if it exists you exit function.

```
<?php
    //add action give it the name of our function to run
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wcs_stock_text_shop_page', 25 );
    //create our function
    function wcs_stock_text_shop_page() {
        //returns an array with 2 items availability and class for CSS
        global $product;

        $meta = get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), '_ywpo_preorder', true);
        if($meta)
        {
            return;
        }

        $availability = $product->get_availability();
        //check if availability in the array = string 'Out of Stock'
        //if so display on page.//if you want to display the 'in stock' messages as well just leave out this, == 'Out of stock'
        if ( $availability['availability'] == 'Out of stock') {
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_html', '<p class="stock ' . esc_attr( $availability['class'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $availability['availability'] ) . '</p>', $availability['availability'] );
        }
     
    }
```